# Using or avoiding "both" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I am confused about when to use "both" and when to avoid it in the following sentence:

> 1. These scientists' research aims to understand fundamental questions and (to) find clinical applications based on this understanding.
> 2. These scientists' research aims to *both* understand fundamental questions and (to) find clinical applications based on this understanding.

Comment: A list of all the situations where you *should not* use "both" would be quite long.  In this case either is fine.  Perhaps if you add more detail why you find this confusing, we could write a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "both" simply emphasizes the two objectives. Since the two objectives are stated explicitly, the meaning is clear with or without the word "both". However, I would suggest one of two phrasings.

> 1. These scientists' research aims to both understand fundamental questions and find clinical applications based on this understanding.
> 2. These scientists' research aims both to understand fundamental questions and to find clinical applications based on this understanding.

If you want to omit "to" in the second infinitive, I suggest that you place "both" after the "to" in the first infinitive (as in the first example). However, if you want to include "to" in both infinitives, I would place "both" before "to understand" (as in the second example).

Comment: It's true that "both" provides a degree of emphasis, but this is relatively "weak" in the cited context. If the speaker *really* wanted to emphasise the plurality of objectives, he'd more likely say *These scientists' research aims **not only** to understand fundamental questions, **but also** to find clinical applications based on this understanding.*